# The boundary of a bounded open set is not contractible

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a bounded open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$: it is well-known that the fact that a retraction of $\overline{\Omega}$ onto its boundary $\partial\Omega$ cannot exist can be directly deduced from its truth for $\Omega=B^n$. 
(In fact we can assume that $\Omega\subseteq B^n$ and if $f$ is such a retraction  we can extend it to $\overline{B^n}\setminus\overline{\Omega}$ with the identity; then we compose $f$ with a radial projection from an interior point of $\Omega$ onto $\partial B^n$: this is a retraction of $\overline{B^n}$ onto its boundary, contradiction). 
Now the question: **is such a direct reduction possible also to prove that $\partial\Omega$ is not contractible?** 
(I know this can be proved by means of the notion of degree, but I'd like to see if it reduces to some general theorems on the topology of $B^n$).

Comment: Incidentally, your proof of nonexistence of retraction to the boundary of a bounded domain is wrong and I do not see how to save it.

Comment: What do you think is going wrong with the proof? The extension of $f$ fixes $\partial B^n$, so when we compose it with the radial projection we obtain a retraction.

Comment: Your proof is just fine, I just misunderstood what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Use Alexander duality to show that the $(n-1)$st Chech cohomology of the boundary of a bounded nonempty open subset $\Omega$ is nonzero.

As for your request for an 'elementary' proof, I am not sure it can be done without introducing something like Chech cohomology, since there exists a continuous 1-1 map of a line to the plane whose image bounds a bounded domain.

Comment: Yes I know it can be solved with advanced tools, I wanted to know if it can be deduced in some way from the fact that $S^{n-1}$ is not contractible or similar statements about the ball/spere alone.

Comment: The boundary in your case does not even have homology of the sphere. Furthermore, even in the sphere case, to prove non-contractibility you have to invoke homology or something similar. Lastly, think of contractibility of the unit sphere in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.